# Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status tomcat.service' for details.

I have checked many times it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact comands but for me it was a permission issue.
I gave permissions to user tomcat but tried to run service as default user.
Look for read/write permission and make sure you have them correctly.